# Can't connect to a remote DB2 using a virtual machine

Tags: perl, db2, dbi

I have a perl script running on a Debian virtual machine on VMWare. This script is supposed to connect to a DB2 database running on my Windows 7. When I try to connect with that string:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:DB2:DATABASE='nmap'; HOSTNAME='192.168.252.167'; PORT='50000'; PROTOCOL=TCPIP; UID='db2admin'; PASSWORD='password'";
```

The program returns an error and it says that db2 is not installed on Debian. How can I tell my script that the DB is running on a different machine? The virtual machine has a bridged connection with 192.168.252.178 as IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `DBD::DB2` package installed on the client machine (your Debian VM in this case) if you want to connect to a DB2 database with `DBI`.

Comment: Furthermore, DBD::DB2 depends on having the DB2 client installed on your Linux box, too.

Comment: Found out DB2 client wasnt installed correctly. Thanks anyway.